# OBIEE 11g not working : not entering to analytics?

Tags: weblogic11g, obiee

i'm using OBIEE 11g, and i have a problem with logging into the analytics, i post my username and password, but it tells me invalid username !!
here follows the entire stacktrace of the problem ( WebLogic ) :

```
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactor
yToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.inject.BindingBuilderImpl$FactoryProxy.get(BindingBuilderI
mpl.java:299)
        at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToI
nternalFactoryAdapter.java:37)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:756)
        at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInte
rnalFactoryAdapter.java:35)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactor
yToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$SingleParameterInjector.inject(Injecto
rImpl.java:640)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Error while locating instance
  bound to com.sigmadynamics.server.SDClusterInterface
  for member at com.sigmadynamics.cluster.RpcLocalExecutor.<init>(RpcLocalExecut
or.java:21)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$SingleParameterInjector.inject(Injecto
rImpl.java:646)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.getParameters(InjectorImpl.java:666)
        at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.j
ava:140)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$ImplicitBinding.get(InjectorImpl.java:
1006)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$SingleParameterInjector.inject(Injecto
rImpl.java:640)
        ... 81 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Error while locating instance
  bound to com.sigmadynamics.sdo.util.StringCatalogInterface
  for member at com.sigmadynamics.server.SDCluster.<init>(SDCluster.java:93)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$SingleParameterInjector.inject(Injecto
rImpl.java:646)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.getParameters(InjectorImpl.java:666)
        at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.j
ava:140)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$ImplicitBinding.get(InjectorImpl.java:
1006)
        at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToI
nternalFactoryAdapter.java:37)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:756)
        at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInte
rnalFactoryAdapter.java:35)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactor
yToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$SingleParameterInjector.inject(Injecto
rImpl.java:640)
        ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExcepti
on
        at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.j
ava:161)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$ImplicitBinding.get(InjectorImpl.java:
1006)
        at com.google.inject.BindingBuilderImpl$FactoryProxy.get(BindingBuilderI
mpl.java:299)
        at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToI
nternalFactoryAdapter.java:37)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:756)
        at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInte
rnalFactoryAdapter.java:35)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactor
yToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$SingleParameterInjector.inject(Injecto
rImpl.java:640)
        ... 94 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.sigmadynamics.sdo.util.StringCatalog$$FastClassByGuice$$c75b3a0e.
newInstance(<generated>)
        at com.google.inject.cglib.reflect.FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConst
ructor.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$2.newInstance(Defau
ltConstructionProxyFactory.java:67)
        at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.j
ava:142)
        ... 102 more
Caused by: com.sigmadynamics.server.DataServices.DatabaseProvider.DatabaseProvid
erException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceDeadException: 0:weblogic.comm
on.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection. The DBMS driver exceptio
n was: Erreur d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.JDBCUtil.wrapAndThrowResourceException(
JDBCUtil.java:250)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getPoolConnection(RmiData
Source.java:352)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSour
ce.java:369)
        at com.sigmadynamics.server.SDDataSource.getConnection(SDDataSource.java
:85)
        at com.sigmadynamics.server.DataServices.DatabaseProvider.DatabaseInfo.c
reateNewInstance(DatabaseInfo.java:145)
        at com.sigmadynamics.server.DataServices.DatabaseProvider.DatabaseInfo.g
etInstance(DatabaseInfo.java:134)
        at com.sigmadynamics.server.DataServices.DatabaseProvider.DatabaseProvid
er.<init>(DatabaseProvider.java:126)
        at com.sigmadynamics.server.DataServices.DatabaseProvider.DatabaseProvid
er.<init>(DatabaseProvider.java:110)
        at com.sigmadynamics.server.SDDatabase.getDefaultDatabase(SDDatabase.jav
a:37)
        at com.sigmadynamics.sdo.util.StringCatalog.<init>(StringCatalog.java:31
)
        ... 106 more
Caused by: weblogic.jdbc.extensions.ConnectionDeadSQLException: weblogic.common.
resourcepool.ResourceDeadException: 0:weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could n
ot create pool connection. The DBMS driver exception was: Erreur d'E/S: The Netw
ork Adapter could not establish the connection
        ... 116 more

        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.jav
a:1510)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineD
river.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStat
eDriver.java:119)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.jdbc.extensions.ConnectionDeadSQLException: weblogic.common.
resourcepool.ResourceDeadException: 0:weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could n
ot create pool connection. The DBMS driver exception was: Erreur d'E/S: The Netw
ork Adapter could not establish the connection
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.JDBCUtil.wrapAndThrowResourceException(
JDBCUtil.java:250)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getPoolConnection(RmiData
Source.java:352)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSour
ce.java:369)
        at com.sigmadynamics.server.SDDataSource.getConnection(SDDataSource.java
:85)
        at com.sigmadynamics.server.DataServices.DatabaseProvider.DatabaseInfo.c
reateNewInstance(DatabaseInfo.java:145)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
PostInstallConfigIntegration:oracle_ias_farm target auth registration is done.
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Warning> <org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.G
lobalConfiguratorImpl> <BEA-000000> <Services de configuration d├®j├á initialis├
®s.>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The Server has
established connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service successfully.>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state ch
anged to ADMIN>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state ch
anged to RESUMING>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is
 now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:10c:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap,
snmp, http.>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is no
w listening on 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:28fe:14bc:3f57:fef3:7001 for protocols iiop, t3,
 ldap, snmp, http.>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[3]" is
 now listening on fe80:0:0:0:28fe:14bc:3f57:fef3:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ld
ap, snmp, http.>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Warning> <Server> <BEA-002611> <Hostname "mehdi-PC", m
aps to multiple IP addresses: 192.168.1.12, fe80:0:0:0:2d02:7435:4101:c003%11, f
e80:0:0:0:28fe:14bc:3f57:fef3%15, 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:28fe:14bc:3f57:fef3>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[4]" is
 now listening on fe80:0:0:0:9474:8ca9:1784:bd10:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ld
ap, snmp, http.>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[8]" is
 now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.
>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[5]" is
 now listening on fe80:0:0:0:2c50:85e6:e9d8:158f:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ld
ap, snmp, http.>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[6]" is
 now listening on fe80:0:0:0:2d02:7435:4101:c003:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ld
ap, snmp, http.>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[7]" is
 now listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is
 now listening on 192.168.1.12:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000329> <Started WebLogi
c Admin Server "AdminServer" for domain "bifoundation_domain" running in Product
ion Mode>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state ch
anged to RUNNING>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started
in RUNNING mode>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no d
ata read from it on fe80:0:0:0:2d02:7435:4101:c003:50┬á435 during the configured
 idle timeout of 5 secs>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no d
ata read from it on fe80:0:0:0:2d02:7435:4101:c003:50┬á431 during the configured
 idle timeout of 5 secs>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no d
ata read from it on fe80:0:0:0:2d02:7435:4101:c003:50┬á433 during the configured
 idle timeout of 5 secs>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no d
ata read from it on fe80:0:0:0:2d02:7435:4101:c003:50┬á434 during the configured
 idle timeout of 5 secs>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no d
ata read from it on fe80:0:0:0:2d02:7435:4101:c003:50┬á432 during the configured
 idle timeout of 5 secs>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Warning> <oracle.wsm.resources.policyaccess> <WSM-0621
0> <Une instance du bean interface oracle.wsm.policymanager.IUsageTracker pour l
e r├®f├®rentiel local sur le chemin "" n'├®tait pas disponible pour la configura
tion de la m├®thode d'acc├¿s de r├®f├®rentiel oracle.wsm.policymanager.accessor.
BeanAccessor dans le contexte "ResourcePattern [pattern=DOMAIN/weblogic/bifounda
tion_domain, subjectType=MANAGED_DOMAIN, terms={PLATFORM=weblogic, SUBJECT_TYPE=
MANAGED_DOMAIN, DOMAIN=bifoundation_domain}]".>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Warning> <oracle.wsm.resources.policyaccess> <WSM-0621
0> <Une instance du bean interface oracle.wsm.policymanager.IDocumentManager pou
r le r├®f├®rentiel local sur le chemin "" n'├®tait pas disponible pour la config
uration de la m├®thode d'acc├¿s de r├®f├®rentiel oracle.wsm.policymanager.access
or.BeanAccessor dans le contexte "ResourcePattern [pattern=DOMAIN/weblogic/bifou
ndation_domain, subjectType=MANAGED_DOMAIN, terms={PLATFORM=weblogic, SUBJECT_TY
PE=MANAGED_DOMAIN, DOMAIN=bifoundation_domain}]".>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Warning> <oracle.wsm.resources.policyaccess> <WSM-0621
0> <Une instance du bean interface oracle.wsm.policymanager.IUsageTracker pour l
e r├®f├®rentiel local sur le chemin "" n'├®tait pas disponible pour la configura
tion de la m├®thode d'acc├¿s de r├®f├®rentiel oracle.wsm.policymanager.accessor.
BeanAccessor dans le contexte "ResourcePattern [pattern=DOMAIN/weblogic/bifounda
tion_domain, subjectType=MANAGED_DOMAIN, terms={PLATFORM=weblogic, SUBJECT_TYPE=
MANAGED_DOMAIN, DOMAIN=bifoundation_domain}]".>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Warning> <oracle.wsm.resources.policyaccess> <WSM-0621
0> <Une instance du bean interface oracle.wsm.policymanager.IDocumentManager pou
r le r├®f├®rentiel local sur le chemin "" n'├®tait pas disponible pour la config
uration de la m├®thode d'acc├¿s de r├®f├®rentiel oracle.wsm.policymanager.access
or.BeanAccessor dans le contexte "ResourcePattern [pattern=DOMAIN/weblogic/bifou
ndation_domain, subjectType=MANAGED_DOMAIN, terms={PLATFORM=weblogic, SUBJECT_TY
PE=MANAGED_DOMAIN, DOMAIN=bifoundation_domain}]".>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Error> <oracle.webservices.service> <OWS-04086> <oracl
e.fabric.common.PolicyEnforcementException: PolicySet Invalid: WSM-06102 PolicyR
eference L'URI de r├®f├®rence de strat├®gie "oracle/wss_username_token_service_p
olicy" n'est pas valide.
        at oracle.integration.platform.common.InterceptorChainImpl.createPolicyE
nforcementException(InterceptorChainImpl.java:305)
        at oracle.integration.platform.common.InterceptorChainImpl.processReques
t(InterceptorChainImpl.java:151)
        at oracle.integration.platform.common.mgmt.InterceptorChainManager.proce
ssRequest(InterceptorChainManager.java:276)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.mgmt.runtime.SuperServerInterceptorPipeline.han
dleRequest(SuperServerInterceptorPipeline.java:165)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.provider.management.AbstractProviderInterceptor
Pipeline.executeRequestInterceptorChain(AbstractProviderInterceptorPipeline.java
:576)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.provider.ProviderProcessor.executeInterceptorRe
questChain(ProviderProcessor.java:921)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.WebServiceProcessor.processRequest(WebServicePr
ocessor.java:231)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.WebServiceProcessor.doService(WebServiceProcess
or.java:193)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.WebServiceServlet.doPost(WebServiceServlet.java
:485)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run
(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecuri
tyHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.jav
a:300)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.ja
va:56)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)

        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:31
5)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUt
il.java:442)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.jav
a:103)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:1
71)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.ja
va:56)
        at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:13
9)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.ja
va:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationActio
n.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationActio
n.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(Authenticate
dSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:
120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppS
ervletContext.java:2277)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletC
ontext.java:2183)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.j
ava:1454)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
>
<4 mai 2013 14 h 50 WET> <Error> <oracle.webservices.service> <OWS-04115> <Une e
rreur s'est produite pour le port : {http://oracle/bi/security/}SecurityServiceP
ort : oracle.fabric.common.PolicyEnforcementException: PolicySet Invalid: WSM-06
102 PolicyReference L'URI de r├®f├®rence de strat├®gie "oracle/wss_username_toke
n_service_policy" n'est pas valide. .>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to connect to EM and console with weblogic account? If yes then do the following....

The BISystemUser account has become locked.

You have to create a new user with the same privileges and permissions

1.Log in to the WebLogic Server Administration Console.

2.Create a new user and assign it to the Administrators Group.

3.Log in to Enterprise Manager to Add this new user to 'BISystem' Role.

4.Navigate to 'Weblogic Domain > bifoundation_domain'

5.Right click on bifoundation_domain.

6.From the resulting menu, click on Security/Credentials menu item
In the Credentials Screen expand oracle.bi.system.
Choose 'system.user' and click 'Edit'
In the resulting pop-up window, enter the new user name and password

7.Re-start the OBIEE components, Managed Server and Admin Server.
After ten minutes log in to Answers as the new user.

If issue still persist change the Password for RPD file which you have deployed ,
(Same old password you can reenter here )

1) Open RPD in  BI Administration Tool - Offline Mode
2) Go to File - > Change Password - >
3) if there is weblogic user exist in RPD , delete the weblogic user in RPD ( In Manage -> Identity )
4) Save the RPD
5) Restart the service and try to login again